# How to print a hbase table to a tab separated text file

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive

I am trying to find a way to read an hbase query result into a tab separated text file.

Structure of hbase table `people`:

```
12 column-name=name;value=John Smith
10 column-name=name;value=Jack Johnson
```

I want to output it in a text file which is created like this:

```
- 12(tab)John Smith
- 10(tab)Jack Johnson
```

Is there any tool available for this, like the export is available for outputting hbase to hdfs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to export a complete table HBase ships with a utility to do that see [here](http://hbase.apache.org/book/ops_mgt.html#export)

Another option is to use Pig which will also let you manipulate /filter etc the results before you export e.g.

```
SOURCE = LOAD 'hbase://tableName'
       USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage(
       'cfName:name', '-loadKey true')
       AS (id:bytearray, name:chararray);

-- do some filtering or other manipulation here
STORE SOURCE INTO '/result_file' USING PigStorage('\t');
```

edit: and I just noticed this is tagged with hive so if you are using that you can do something like `INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/result_file' SELECT * FROM table_name;` (replace the select with your query)

Comment: thanks a lot!! I will try it and let you know, our grid is down so cant test it immidiately

Comment: tried the export !! works...however, when I try to hadoop dfs -text the file, I get is a classname missing exception for
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: WritableName can't load class: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310177/sequence-files-created-by-hbase-export-utility-arent-readable