# sequence files created by HBASE export utility aren't readable

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, sequencefile

I tried the HBase export tool to transfer a table to HDFS. I tried to `hadoop dfs -text` the file to see a collection of contents. However, I got a fatal error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: WritableName can't load class: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
```

Do I need to integrate any configuration to include the class in my hadoop runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sequenceFile is a binary format. you can access it using Hadoop programing API or you can try a tool like [forklift](http://www.exmachinatech.net/01/forqlift/)

Comment: however, control-A separated seq files work with dfs -text command. let me try.